# Problem with different Vuforia ImageTargets in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Can anyone explain me why this Vuforia Image Target [Image Target with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faDMI.png) displays 3D-models with twitching in Unity and this Image Target [Image Target with no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge910.png) not?
Resolution of both pictures is only in the preview of Vuforia bad.

Both picture have a 5 star rating from Vuforia and the amount of Feature Points seems equally, if not better in the one with the problem.

- [Feature points of Image Target with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znIjT.png)
- [Feature points of Image Target with no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMXpt.png)

I am currently using Unity 2019.3.6f1 and Vuforia 8.6.10 on macOS Catalina.

Thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: does both markers have the same size typed at vufroia site?

Comment: yeah they both have the size 5 @NikolayGonza